# DateTimeOffset precision doesn’t match between EF and NPGSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

#### Steps to reproduce

So I have an integration test that creates a user in by db and then confirms that it was accurately created. See the test and full working repo [here](https://github.com/pdevito3/postgres-docker-integration-tests/blob/master/Accessioning/tests/Accessioning.IntegrationTests/FeatureTests/Patient/AddPatientCommandTests.cs).

The test looks like this:

```cs
        [Test]
        public async Task AddPatientCommand_Adds_New_Patient_To_Db()
        {
            // Arrange
            var fakePatientOne = new FakePatientForCreationDto { }.Generate();

            // Act
            var command = new AddPatientCommand(fakePatientOne);
            var patientReturned = await SendAsync(command);
            var patientCreated = await ExecuteDbContextAsync(db => db.Patients.SingleOrDefaultAsync());

            // Assert
            patientReturned.Should().BeEquivalentTo(fakePatientOne, options =>
                options.ExcludingMissingMembers());
            patientCreated.Should().BeEquivalentTo(fakePatientOne, options =>
                options.ExcludingMissingMembers());
        }
```

It works and passes with sql server and is seemingly working here as well, but the test is failing due to what looks like a precision issue on a `DateTimeOffset?` property.

I would expect the test to pass, but it would seem that the precision between a datetimeoffset in EF and npgsql doesn't match. As you can see in the error message, the `Dob` property is matching, save for the extra `2` in the EF object. I would expect the npgsql retrieved value to match.

Any thoughts on what’s going on here and how I may be able to fix it? Thinking it could be a bug in the library.

```
Message: 
    Expected member Dob to be <2021-03-22 22:45:15.0749082 -4h>, but found <2021-03-22 22:45:15.074908 -4h>.
    
    With configuration:
    - Use declared types and members
    - Compare enums by value
    - Try to match member by name
    - Without automatic conversion.
    - Be strict about the order of items in byte arrays
    
  Stack Trace: 
    LateBoundTestFramework.Throw(String message)
    TestFrameworkProvider.Throw(String message)
    CollectingAssertionStrategy.ThrowIfAny(IDictionary`2 context)
    EquivalencyValidator.AssertEquality(EquivalencyValidationContext context)
    ObjectAssertions.BeEquivalentTo[TExpectation](TExpectation expectation, Func`2 config, String because, Object[] becauseArgs)
    AddPatientCommandTests.AddPatientCommand_Adds_New_Patient_To_Db() line 28
    GenericAdapter`1.BlockUntilCompleted()
    NoMessagePumpStrategy.WaitForCompletion(AwaitAdapter awaitable)
    AsyncToSyncAdapter.Await(Func`1 invoke)
    TestMethodCommand.RunTestMethod(TestExecutionContext context)
    TestMethodCommand.Execute(TestExecutionContext context)
    <>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Execute>b__0()
    BeforeAndAfterTestCommand.RunTestMethodInThreadAbortSafeZone(TestExecutionContext context, Action action)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can ignore tiny imprecise things like this (1millionth of a second).

```
patientReturned.Should().BeEquivalentTo(fakePatientOne,
            opt => opt
                .Using<DateTime>(su => su.Subject.Should().BeCloseTo(su.Expectation, 10)) <-- 10 ms is close enough
                   .WhenTypeIs<DateTime>()
```

Comment: yeah. don't really feel like it's something that one should have to worry about and clog up my code with.

Comment: It's really a floating point problem, and you will have the same problem there too.

Comment: odd that it happens in npgsql and not sql server db though. would expect some consistency in the orm

Comment: Postgres is not  MS SqlServer. Why are you supervised there is differences. Without table with column definitions I cannot be sure but it looks like your field in question is defines as timestamp. This default to 6 digits of precision. Your test is looking for 7. If so then you can change that columns definition to timestamp(7).

Comment: Yes, I’m aware they aren’t the same thing... but if I have an entity with a DateTimeOffset property and I’ve set up by DB from migrations, I would expect the precision to be the same. The shouldn’t have to be extra config knowledge required to add some specific workaround every time a date time offset is used.

Comment: I used PG on a project a few years back, and the database driver (Pomelo?) wasn't very good back then, so it doesn't surprise me that fields in migrations aren't entirely matched up to C# expectations.   Take a look at the migrations, there might be some tweaks you need to manually make to the precision properties when creating DateTimeOffset fields.